# flask-wtforms update object with preselection of selectField not working

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to update an object, which is working fine except for my selectFields with a preselection:

routes.py:

```
form_inquiry = ViewInquiryForm()     

form_inquiry.taskID.choices = [(g.id, g.taskDescription) for g in InquiryTask.query.all()]
form_inquiry.taskID.process_data(resultInquiry.taskID)

if request.method == 'GET':
   form_inquiry.lastEditByID = resultUser.username
   return render_template('main/viewInquiry.html', form_inquiry=form_inquiry)

if form_inquiry.validate_on_submit():
    inquiry = resultInquiry
    inquiry.lastEditByID = current_user.id
    inquiry.taskID = form_inquiry.taskID.data
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('main.viewInquiries'))
```

I want to preselect the current taskID in the selectField field, which represents the currently taskID for this inquiry within the database with the following command:

```
form_inquiry.taskID.process_data(resultInquiry.taskID)
```

This is working fine but when I am using it, a new, different selection of taskID in the selectField is not applied. The record will not update this property. form_inquiry.taskID.data will remain the preselected value.
When I remove the preselection it is working fine.

So, is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set your preselected value on the GET request, and don't do any preselecting during the POST request.

```
form_inquiry = ViewInquiryForm()     

form_inquiry.taskID.choices = [(g.id, g.taskDescription) for g in InquiryTask.query.all()]

if request.method == 'GET':
    form_inquiry.taskID.process_data(resultInquiry.taskID)
    form_inquiry.lastEditByID = resultUser.username
    return render_template('main/viewInquiry.html', form_inquiry=form_inquiry)
```

Comment: It is working fine. I guess I was blinded by the fact that "form.xyz.choices" has do be done before! Thank you. You saved me a lot of time.